# Set Thread Priority

Tags: spring

I need to kick off a thread to clean up data in the background after a user signs in our application. The data clean-up method is with @Async annotation in Spring. Due to the nature of the thread, I would like to set the thread to a low priority so that it would not complete the resource with the main functionality of the application. I can do so in the getAsyncExecutor method of the AsyncConfiguration class. Is the priority for the particular thread?

BTW, I don't find any methods with @Async annotation.

Comment: Does it answer your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792840/understanding-priority-in-java-threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Async` allows you to configure a qualifier. It will then use the `AsyncTaskExecutor` bean configured with the same qualifier to start the thread to execute this async method. Most of the `AsyncTaskExecutor` implementation allows to configure the thread priority.

For example, if the method is defined as  :

```java
@Async("backgroundJobTaskExecutor")
public void doJob(){
  
}
```

You can then define a `AsyncTaskExecutor` bean as :

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("backgroundJobTaskExecutor")
public AsyncTaskExecutor backgroundJobTaskExecutor(){
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setThreadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Threads managed by a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor are released and reused later on demand. So changing their priorities can have unintended consequences. I think it would be better to spawn a dedicated thread in your method once executed and then proceed to fine tune its priority. As in the following example:

```java
    public void launchMaintenanceTask(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            doYourMaintenanceStuffHere();
        });
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: That was something I had in mind when I asked this question.